# Just need to know if the way i have used the operator module, operator functions of python in the below program is appropriate?

Tags: python-3.x

Below program accepts the choice from the user, (add, sub, mul, div) and then performs the operation according to choice on the 2 numbers given as input by the user. Just need to know the way i have used the operator functions as dict values to accomplish the task is its appropriate use ? Can i use lambda functions  as dict values in the place of these operator functions ?

```
import operator
def opnnum(opn, x, y):
    d ={"add" : operator.add,
        "mul":operator.mul,
        "div":operator.truediv,
        "sub":operator.sub}
    return d[opn](x,y)

op = input("Enter add for +, sub for -, mul for * and div for /")
n1 = int(input("Enter first number"))
m1 = int(input("Enter second number"))
print("The answer of operation",op, "is",opnnum(op, n1, m1))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "appropriate use"? Does your program behave as expected? If you are wondering whether a ``lambda`` expression can be used as a dict value, have you tried it?

Comment: i mean to say if i place a lambda function as a dict value in place of the operator function ..does it violates PEP 8 guidelines ? PEP 8 clearly says we should not use lambda function with assignment statement , if i place a lambda function as a value of dict , the key becomes the reference to that lambda function . kindly make it clear to me

Comment: Dictionary values are not assignment statements.

Comment: i have tested  this code with lambda, and it is perfectly working . So according to you it is ok to use lambda in this situation .... ?